# Can't send UTF-8 data through PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a file called **index.php** which contains a form, which redirects the page to itself, and awaits some `UTF-8` encoded data. My problem is, that the data that is sent through the form is exchanged to question marks by the browser.

Here's the code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
   if($_POST["action"] == "insert"){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";

        echo "Some simple UTF-8 text: țșțțáéáéáőúőúőúőúőúőúő";
   }
 ?>

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert">
        <input type="text" name="article_date" class="form-control" size="15" id="article_date" value="">
        <input type="text" name="test_field" value="áááéáéáéáéáéá">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="article_title" placeholder="Some placeholder" value="">
    </form>
   </body>
```

If I run this file, and just send the form, as it is, I get this output:

> Array 
>   ( 
>       [action] => insert 
>       [article_date] => 
>       [test_field] => ��������������������������������������� 
>       [title] => 
>   ) 
> Some simple UTF-8 text: țșțțáéáéáőúőúőúőúőúőúő

So, what I gather from this, is that basically UTF-8 encoding in the browser is working, as the plain UTF-8 echo is displayed correctly, but when I try to send UTF-8 data through `POST`, it is not decoded correctly. What could a possible solution to this problem be?

Comment: Did you try to use htmlspecialchars($_POST['value']);

Comment: tried it now, no success:|

Comment: When you gave UTF-8 char statically in the editor it decodes it. I faced the same problem in sublime.

Comment: 1) Can you double check in the browser's inspector tools that the **Content-Type HTTP header** is actually sent correctly and not possibly overridden by your web server? 2) Do you have anything in your php.ini relating to `mbstring.http_input` or such set?

Comment: we are right now experimenting based on another answer from another question, with your point 2.). content type in the inspector tools seems to be UTF-8, so I don't think the problem comes from there:|

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `php.ini` files has `default_charset = "utf-8";`
2. (Done) have on your PHP header: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
3. (Almost done) in your HTML page:   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
4. And forehand, check the default encoding of the text editor you are using to write the code and if not, set it to UTF-8.
5. Check httpd.conf (assuming you are using Apache) and check `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` is set.
6. If using it, add in .htaccess `IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

try this..

I am using Notepad++ for this...

First time create new file and paste this code only..

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
```

After Save you file and close it. And check on Browser...

**IMPORTANT: Don't Forgot to Close your file and Reopen..**

Now once again open your file and paste this code...

```
<?php
   if($_POST["action"] == "insert"){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";

        echo "Some simple UTF-8 text: țșțțáéáéáőúőúőúőúőúőúő";
   }
 ?>

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert">
        <input type="text" name="article_date" class="form-control" size="15" id="article_date" value="">
        <input type="text" name="test_field" value="áááéáéáéáéáéá">
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="article_title" placeholder="Some placeholder" value="">
    </form>
   </body>
```

Then save your file and check it..

Basically First time our browser doesn't understand utf-8...after once upload the browser working fine...

Answer (score -1):

The data entering your database is not uploading in UTF8 format.

Make sure :

- use `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8` when creating new tables
- use `SET NAMES utf8` before you query/insert into the database

Or you should set charset during database connection `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`